# How can I fast discharge Li-Po battery?

Tags: batteries

I have a 11.1V li po battery (3S). I wanted to drain it fast so I could test a charger circuitry. How can I do that fast. Unfortunately, I do not have high current consuming loads which can drain a batt and then I do the test.

Comment: You could try a pencil (contact the graphite - not the wood).

Comment: is 4Ah and LiPol chemistry. It is 3S (series).

Comment: I agree with apalopohapa - use two pins (or needles) to poke through a standard pencil (make sure to measure the resistance, it should be a couple of ohms, depending on the distance between the pins) - the pencil may become warm to the touch, but shouldn't pose a fire hazard if you keep it connected only a short amount of time (a couple hours until the battery is drained).

Comment: Forget using a pencil. 40 Wh discharged through a pencil in say 15 minutes will produce 16 A, 160 W. The pencil will start glowing and catch fire, and the pins will melt at the tips.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a **dummy load**. This is simply a resistor of a suitable value. Most likely, it'll be a low resistance, and it'll dissipate a large amount of power. It may need a heatsink. You can calculate the resistance by using Ohm's Law on the battery voltage and the desired current.

Comment: I had a cool idea the other day for this dummy load thing, you can use some of the available power to run a little fan or two, to cool your power resistors!

Comment: thank u sir. But it will be a resistor of high wattage. And unfortunately I dont have such a one :(

Comment: @VinodKaruvat buy one! If you want to do it properly, and know almost exactly what load and discharge rate you have, then do it the proper way with resistors.

Answer (score 1):

In a pinch, you can make a [water resistor](http://home.earthlink.net/~jimlux/hv/rwater.htm).  But it's actually quite hard to get them right, and easy to make a lot of corrosive mess.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @John H's answer, you can make a useful 12v dummy load. Buy one of those cheap USB car chargers, tear it apart, connect the battery terminals to the positive and negative points on the board inside and charge your Phone, and every other USB device you can find (like Sat-Nav's, Power Banks, etc).

That should drain the battery in a few hours, and you're not wasting loads of energy by dumping loads of energy into a resistor! 
Also you get to play games while waiting for the battery to discharge! It's a win-win situation!

Comment: Please can you tell me why I have been downvoted? Thanks

Comment: Thank u sir. I will def try it. I did not down vote u.